# Unable to loop over list using for_each

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I want to reserve an IP and then use it. If I create a separate `google_compute_address` block for each IP, it works well. But since I want to make the code as dry and optimized as possible, I am learning how to loop and use `for_each`

My **main.tf** looks like this

```
module "nat" {
  source  = "../../modules/nat"

  reserved_ips = [
    {
      name = "gke-frontend-prod-lb"
      ip = "10.238.232.10"
    },
    {
      name = "gke-frontend-test-lb"
      ip = "10.238.232.11"
    }
  ]
}
```

As you can see, I would like to form a list of reserved IPs having name and IP.

Now lets look at my module

My **variables.tf** looks like

```
variable "reserved_ips" {
  type        = list(object({
    name = string
    ip = string
  }))
  description = <<EOF
Reserved IPs.
EOF
}
```

And the **main.tf** of my module looks like

```
locals {
  ips = {
    # for_each needs transform to map
    for ip in var.reserved_ips : "${ip.name}" => "${ip.ip}"
  }
}


resource "google_compute_address" "gke-frontend" {
  for_each = local.ips

  name         = "${each.value.name}"
  subnetwork   = "mysubnet"
  address_type = "INTERNAL"
  address      = "${each.value.ip}"
}
```

But running the code gives me

```
Error: Unsupported attribute

  on ../../modules/nat/main.tf line 11, in resource "google_compute_address" "gke-frontend":
  11:   name         = "${each.value.name}"
    |----------------
    | each.value is "10.238.232.10"

This value does not have any attributes.


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on ../../modules/nat/main.tf line 11, in resource "google_compute_address" "gke-frontend":
  11:   name         = "${each.value.name}"
    |----------------
    | each.value is "10.238.232.11"

This value does not have any attributes.


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on ../../modules/nat/main.tf line 14, in resource "google_compute_address" "gke-frontend":
  14:   address      = "${each.value.ip}"
    |----------------
    | each.value is "10.238.232.10"

This value does not have any attributes.


Error: Unsupported attribute

  on ../../modules/nat/main.tf line 14, in resource "google_compute_address" "gke-frontend":
  14:   address      = "${each.value.ip}"
    |----------------
    | each.value is "10.238.232.11"

This value does not have any attributes.
```

Im confused as to what am I missing here exactly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that your `ips` local converts the list to a `map(string)` (i.e. a map with string values)

```
locals {
  ips = {
    # for_each needs transform to map
    for ip in var.reserved_ips : "${ip.name}" => "${ip.ip}"
  }
}
```

Notice that on the right-side of `=>` you have `"${ip.ip}"`.

When `for_each` loops over a `map` it assigns `each.key` to each key (a `string`) and `each.value` to each corresponding value in the map (in this case `"${ip.ip}` is also a `string`).

So, I think what you want in this case is something like the following

```
  # ...
  name         = each.key
  # ...
  address      = each.value
  # ...
```